# How to fire event of textbox with OnItemCommand of a repeater , without using LinkButton?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, repeater, asprepeater

I have a repeater with a textbox inside , and I want to fire an event 
when I move from one textbox to another textbox , with the `OnItemCommand` of 
the repeater .

```
<asp:Repeater ID="RptrPeople" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="RptrPeople_ItemDataBound" OnItemCommand="RptrPeople_ItemCommand">
         <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:HiddenField ID="hf" runat="server" Value="<%# Eval(this.ValuedPerson) %>" />
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtDescription" runat="server" IsRequired="false" Visible="true" AutoPostBack="true"  />
         </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

I tried to use the `OnTextChanged` of the Textbox , but I can't get the item that fired the event this way .

Can anyone please advise on a good way to get the item that fires the event , after I moved from one textbox , using the `OnItemCommand`  (for example , I entered `123` in `Textbox #1` , and then moved to `Textbox #2` ... then I want to fire the event that takes care of the Textbox that has the `123` value) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I tried to use the OnTextChanged of the Textbox , but I can't get the
>   item that fired the event this way .

The `sender` argument is always the control that triggered the event:

```
protected void txtDescription_TextChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox txtDescription = (TextBox) sender;
}
```

So you should use this instead of `OnItemCommand` because there the `sender` is the repeater.

If you also need to get the reference of the `HiddenField` use following code:

```
protected void txtDescription_TextChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox txtDescription = (TextBox) sender;
    var item = (RepeaterItem) txtDescription.NamingContainer;
    HiddenField hf = (HiddenField) item.FindControl("hf");
}
```

The `NamingContainer` of any control in a `RepeaterItem` is always the `RepeaterItem`. As an aside, that's working similar for other web-databound controls like `GridView` or `DataList`.

Comment: Thanks , but it doesn't help me much , since I also need to get the hidden field of the reapter , and the sender doesn't include that ...

Comment: That's why I need the repeaterItem , it includes the whole thing

Comment: @ron: i have edited my answer to show you how it works.